# Errors when running make

Tags: linux, makefile

When I type this:

```
make -f gcc.mak depend
```

I get the following errors:

```
/bin/sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
/bin/sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
/bin/sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
/usr/include/../include/limits.h:125: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
cat: obj/gcc/so/dll_main.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so/fstream.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so/strstream.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so/sstream.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so/ios.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so/stdio_streambuf.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so/istream.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so/ostream.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so/iostream.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so/codecvt.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so/collate.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so/ctype.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so/monetary.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so/num_get.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so/num_put.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so/num_get_float.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so/num_put_float.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so/numpunct.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so/time_facets.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so/messages.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so/locale_impl.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so/locale_catalog.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so/facets_byname.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so/complex.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so/complex_io.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so/complex_trig.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so/string.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so/bitset.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so/allocators.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so/c_locale.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so_g/dll_main.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so_g/fstream.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so_g/strstream.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so_g/sstream.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so_g/ios.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so_g/stdio_streambuf.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so_g/istream.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so_g/ostream.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so_g/iostream.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so_g/codecvt.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so_g/collate.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so_g/ctype.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so_g/monetary.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so_g/num_get.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so_g/num_put.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so_g/num_get_float.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so_g/num_put_float.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so_g/numpunct.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so_g/time_facets.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so_g/messages.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so_g/locale_impl.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so_g/locale_catalog.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so_g/facets_byname.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so_g/complex.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so_g/complex_io.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so_g/complex_trig.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so_g/string.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so_g/bitset.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so_g/allocators.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so_g/c_locale.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so_stlg/dll_main.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so_stlg/fstream.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so_stlg/strstream.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so_stlg/sstream.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so_stlg/ios.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so_stlg/stdio_streambuf.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so_stlg/istream.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so_stlg/ostream.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so_stlg/iostream.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so_stlg/codecvt.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so_stlg/collate.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so_stlg/ctype.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so_stlg/monetary.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so_stlg/num_get.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so_stlg/num_put.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so_stlg/num_get_float.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so_stlg/num_put_float.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so_stlg/numpunct.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so_stlg/time_facets.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so_stlg/messages.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so_stlg/locale_impl.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so_stlg/locale_catalog.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so_stlg/facets_byname.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so_stlg/complex.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so_stlg/complex_io.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so_stlg/complex_trig.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so_stlg/string.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so_stlg/bitset.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so_stlg/allocators.d: No such file or directory
cat: obj/gcc/so_stlg/c_locale.d: No such file or directory
make: *** [depend] Error 1
```

This is what is in gcc.mak:

```
# -*- Makefile -*- Time-stamp: <05/12/27 10:54:25 ptr>

SRCROOT := ..
COMPILER_NAME := gcc

STLPORT_INCLUDE_DIR = ../../stlport
include Makefile.inc
include ${SRCROOT}/Makefiles/top.mak

ifeq ($(OSNAME),linux)
DEFS += -D_STLP_REAL_LOCALE_IMPLEMENTED -D_GNU_SOURCE
endif

# options for build with boost support
ifdef STLP_BUILD_BOOST_PATH
INCLUDES += -I$(STLP_BUILD_BOOST_PATH)
endif
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Best over at Stack Overflow. Voted to close/move

Comment: The mods will kick it over...

Comment: There's nothing wrong in `gcc.mak` that I can see, the problem is in one of the included files. Are you running a recent version of GNU make? Check if the makefiles you're including have a documented minimum version requirement.

Comment: The problem is in `Makefile.inc` or `top.mak`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to build STLport yourself. Why not use the version that comes with your distribution?

Looks like Debian faced a similar problem and fixed it a few years ago: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=468063